# Scaling a Restaurant Database in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm designing a back-end for an application that will keep track of several different restaurants and their order history. So I've been thinking about the most efficient way to do this. What I think I want to do have one generic design for any restaurant and create a new database as we add different restaurants. (Please let me know if there is anything wrong with doing it that way)

What I'm trying to figure out is how i'm going to store the specific order data for the restaurants many orders. I was thinking having one large table that keeps track of all the orders and the create a separate mini tables for each order detailing what was ordered, prices, and if any discounts/coupons were applied.

I imagine in one month a restaurant can have thousands of orders, so that would end with me having several thousands of mini tables with separate orders. I was also considering having a table full of each individual item for all orders and just attaching an order_id to each of them. But then I would have a table with up to tens of thousands of entries a month.

Which is the most efficient way to do this? Of course, both these implementation ideas might be way off, so i'm open to hearing any other ideas or thoughts!

Comment: I don't know if SO is the right place for this question, but there are advantages and disadvantages to this `one generic design for any restaurant and create a new database` etc

Comment: I think I would start with any decent book or tutorial on database design and normalisation

Comment: Right now you're at the "I'd like a house and I have a hammer" stage. You need to learn about database design, application design and probably restaurant management. This is much too broad a topic for an answer on a page in stackoverflow.

Comment: "tens of thousands of entries a month"  Some systems handle tens of thousands of entries per hour, if not minute.  What you're talking about might sound like a lot to you, but for a computer, it's nothing.

Comment: Appreciate the advice. For those of you that recommended I look into learning more design, are there any specific resources you would recommend for me? I've taken a DB course before but it was garbage and I learned more by search SO than I did in that class. :/

Comment: This question is opinion based but If I were you I would create a table for order details and use one order_id and one product_id column another table for orders and another one for products, thousands of entries a month is nothing for MySQL Specially you have only 2 INT column in that table , The MyISAM storage engine supports 2^32 rows per table, but you can build MySQL with the --with-big-tables option to make it support up to 2^64 rows per table.

Comment: I would just have one database for this.  Give each Hotel a id and collect the data from there.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better fit for [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Unless you are expecting millions of rows, "scaling" is not yet a problem.  Do not have a separate table for each 'order'.  Ditto for any case of 'identical' structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to sacrifice design for performance when you're not actually needing it. It just makes unnecessary complications. Just try to design your entities in normal forms like [BCNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form) or [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). Then after you designed your entities and everything looks nice about it.

Then there are many solutions for performance tuning and scaling.

The first is [indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index), By indexing, you can save a lot of computational power. Because querying a database without indexes is `O(n)` and by indexes, you can have `O(log(n))` or even `O(1)` depend on the indexing algorithm you are using.

The next solution is [partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(database)) the tables. Think of it as dividing your table into many tables but the database abstracts that and you see only one table.

These two first solutions help you to tune performance in one machine. While scaling up a machine can help you to achieve better performance. There are hardware limitations on that. So if you have to scale out, there is replication and [sharding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)).

Basically, the [replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_(computing)) helps you to scale your read queries. There are replication solutions which can scale write queries but they aren't really super effective as they have to write one thing in all the machines in the cluster. Though they are perfect solutions for high availability.

So if you reach a level that you have so much writes that the replication doesn't help anymore. You can go to the sharding. There are many aspects to sharding. Like is sharding should be done on application level or database level? And how to divide data between machines?

For myself, I prefer the database level sharding (and I actually use it in production). Because the application level sharding could make the application server code complicated (since you may need service discovery, etc.) and even dirty if it isn't handled carefully. Also, the abstraction helps developers to think of the cluster as one database instead of many divided databases.

And for dividing the data between shards. There are vertical sharding and horizontal sharding.

In vertical sharding, you divide the data by entities like customers in one database, orders in another, etc.
This should be the first approach since it's super easier to do than horizontal sharding.

In horizontal sharding, you divide one entity between many database servers. For example, you can use a formula to divide the rows evenly like the rows with odd ID goes to instance A and the rows with even ID goes to instance B.

Another way is to divide them by something common like dividing orders by restaurants.

Hope it helps. If you have further questions, I will be happy to answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply! I appreciate your detailed answer, you've given me a lot to think about! I'll let you know if I have any questions in the future.